# types of classes to serialize de-serialize

Tags: protobuf-net

Is it possible to deserialize from protobuf-net without knowing apriori the type of the object ?
( this is required since I wish to use protobuf-net with ScaleOut software which would eventually store objects of different types so when providing the callback of the serializer method , the object type is not known ).

Answer (score 0):

This depends on a few factors. Firstly, we need to be clear between three different scenarios:

- type known statically as `Foo` - can simply use the generic API
- type not known statically, but the `Type` will be known somehow at runtime - can use the non-generic API
- type not known at all

I'm assuming you mean the third option. This is the most problematic, because protobuf doesn't include type metadata - and indeed the same data can be deserialized as any *compatible* type : it doesn't need to be the same type.

If it is the last case and the data is already serialized, then there aren't many good options except maybe a pure "extensible" type (the `Extensible` base type provides runtime access to unknown fields, and round-trip support). However, it can't materialize into a specific object type because it won't know what type to use.

Protobuf-net does add a "dynamic types" feature which shims over this somewhat, but this would only work for new data - it requires a specific configuration. To be honest, I tend to advise against it - it is complex, and not "standard protobuf".